# Disable other radio buttons in quiz when correct answer is checked

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am using the following code to determine if a checked radio button's value is correct, then disable or hide all of the other radio buttons in the group. This simple setup is part of a quiz I am putting together for a client.

```
<input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one0" class="rsform-radio">
<label for="question-one0">Sight</label>

<input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one1" class="rsform-radio">
<label for="question-one1">Smell</label>

<input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="t" id="question-one2" class="rsform-radio">
<label for="question-one2">Hearing</label>

<input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one3" class="rsform-radio">
<label for="question-one3">Taste</label>

let radios = document.getElementsByName('form[question-one]');
radios.forEach(radio => {
    radio.addEventListener('change', () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            let radiosValue = radios[i];
            if (radiosValue.checked) {
                // The correct answer is marked by the 't' value
                if (radiosValue.value == 't') {
                    // Disable or hide all radio buttons that contain the value of 'f' when checked
                } else {
                    // Incorrect answers are marked with a 'f' value
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this is a best solution.But its solves your problem.Add this inside your `if` statement.

```
if (radiosValue.value == 't') {
    radios.forEach((link)=>{
        if(link.value=='f'){
            link.disabled = true;
        }
    })
}
```